# what is the difference between log4j.properties and logging.properties which are created by google eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, properties, log4j

This is a typical look of the file structure created by Google Plugin for Eclipse:

```
Guestbook/
  src/
    guestbook/
    META-INF/
    log4j.properties
    logging.properties
  war/
    WEB-INF/
```

What is the difference between log4j.properties and logging.properties here?

Answer (score 2):

After everyone started to use Log4J, Sun decided they need to include their own incompatible logging framework as part of the JDK. That is called java.util.logging, and configured by logging.properties. So now you have two, and depending on the code they may use one or the other.

Comment: How do I make sure that it is safe to delete log4j.properties?

Comment: Why do you need to delete it? Nothing really bad is going to happen. Most likely log4j will continue to run with a default configuration, and even if not, the worst that can happen is that log4j messages will be discarded completely. Both of which do not matter unless you want to see those messages.

Comment: It confuses people, other programmers may work with it in vain.